# xcode image gallery load images one after another

Tags: xcode, image, load, uisegmentedcontrol, viewdidload

I am currently developing an iPad app with four views that can be viewed with a segmented control. One of those views is an image gallery I created using UIScrollView. The problem is that all the images are being loaded into the view in the viewDidLoad method and so when I press "images" in the segmented control it takes about a second until the control highlights "images" and shows the view which is very inconvenient. 
I'd like to achieve that when "images" is chosen the segmented control switches immediately and the view is being loaded and then the images should be loaded and put into the scroll view one after another.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code from viewDidLoad?

Are you loading the images from a remote location?

If you are loading the images remotely, you might want to check out:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

It is an async image viewer which also provides an image placeholder while it is loading the image.

Also, you may want to load the images in viewDidAppear, so the view appears and then it starts loading the images...

Comment: Putting the code in viewDidAppear already did a great job. Now I just need to find a way to have the images loaded one after another instead of them being displayed when they are all loaded. How can I achieve that? All images are stored locally btw

Comment: You can still use the link I sent you above for async loading. You can use it with local images too.